# An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a Windows program that calling a WCF service. This service after a few times be strongly slow and eventually this error will encounter. Restart after once again to the service starts again.
sincerely.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for this question to be answered. First off, what is your question? What is the web service doing? Are there errors? What are they? Can you post the calling code as well as the web service code?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably not closing the connection to the WCF service.

WCF has a default of 10 connections and a timeout of one min.

What then happens is that the first 10 hits go OK. The 11th has to wait for an available connection, it will get that after one min when the 1st connections timesout.

The solution is therefore to make sure that you are closing the WCF connections.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on a newly provisioned server where the time on the box was setup incorrectly. Once the server time was correct this error message went away.

See the [following](http://geekswithblogs.net/paulp/archive/2009/08/11/134026.aspx) for more information.