# an unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a Windows program that calling a WCF service. This service after a few times be strongly slow and eventually this error will encounter "an unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party". Restart after once again to the service starts again. sincerely.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839999/an-unsecured-or-incorrectly-secured-fault-was-received-from-the-other-party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there are a thousand reasons why your service might be getting slow.  Most of them will have nothing to do with WCF.  I strongly suspect you have a resource leak of some sort, but it's impossible to tell what it is without more information.